# JsonConvert.SerializeObject ignores subtype

Tags: json.net

I'm using JsonConvert to serialize an object like so:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)
```

Item is an instance of QuestionExtendedView, which looks like this:

```
public class QuestionExtendedView : AuditFullView
{
    public short QuestionNo { get; set; }
    public short TotalQuestions { get; set; }
    public short UnansQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

AuditFullView looks like this:

```
public partial class AuditFullView : EntityObject
{
    public static AuditFullView CreateAuditFullView(global::System.Int32 hAA_ID, global::System.Int16 hAA_Branch, global::System.Int32 hAA_AuditorID, global::System.DateTime hAA_ScheduledDate, global::System.Int32 hAA_TemplateVersionID, global::System.String hAA_Status, global::System.Int32 hAS_ID, global::System.Int32 hAS_AuditID, global::System.Int32 hAS_TemplateSectionID, global::System.Int32 hAE_ID, global::System.Int32 hAE_AuditID, global::System.Int32 hAE_HAS_ID, global::System.Int32 hAE_TemplateElementID, global::System.Int16 hAE_ScriptSequence, global::System.Int32 hAQ_ID, global::System.Int32 hAQ_AuditID, global::System.Int32 hAQ_HAE_ID, global::System.Int32 hAQ_TemplateQuestionID, global::System.Int16 hAQ_ScriptSequence, global::System.Int32 hTS_ID, global::System.Int32 hTS_VersionID, global::System.Int32 hTS_Sequence, global::System.String hTS_SectionName, global::System.Int32 hTE_ID, global::System.Int32 hTE_SectionID, global::System.Int32 hTE_Sequence, global::System.String hTE_Element, global::System.String hTE_Objective, global::System.String hTE_Guidance, global::System.Int32 hTQ_ID, global::System.Int32 hTQ_ElementID, global::System.Int32 hTQ_Sequence, global::System.String hTQ_Question, global::System.Boolean hTQ_WeightedQuestion, global::System.String hSU_Name, global::System.Boolean hAQ_PreviouslyAnsweredQuestion)
    {
        AuditFullView auditFullView = new AuditFullView();
        auditFullView.HAA_ID = hAA_ID;
        auditFullView.HAA_Branch = hAA_Branch;
    // Loads of properties excluded for clarity
        return auditFullView;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 HAA_ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _HAA_ID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_HAA_ID != value)
            {
                OnHAA_IDChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("HAA_ID");
                _HAA_ID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("HAA_ID");
                OnHAA_IDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _HAA_ID;
    partial void OnHAA_IDChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnHAA_IDChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int16 HAA_Branch
    {
        get
        {
            return _HAA_Branch;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_HAA_Branch != value)
            {
                OnHAA_BranchChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("HAA_Branch");
                _HAA_Branch = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("HAA_Branch");
                OnHAA_BranchChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int16 _HAA_Branch;
    partial void OnHAA_BranchChanging(global::System.Int16 value);
    partial void OnHAA_BranchChanged();

// Loads of properties excluded for clarity
}
```

Now, when I run this serialization, I get all the properties from AuditFullView, but not the ones from QuestionExtendedView, as shown with this test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CanSerialize()
    {
        QuestionExtendedView myView = new QuestionExtendedView
                                      {
                                          TotalQuestions = 15,
                                          QuestionNo = 10,
                                          UnansQuestions = 5,
                                          HAA_ID = 100,
                                          HAA_Branch = 213
                                        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myView);

        json.Should().Contain("TotalQuestions");
    }
```

Which fails as the result is:

```
{"$id":"1","HAA_ID":100,"HAA_Branch":213,"EntityKey":null}
```

(again, I have excluded lots of properties from AuditFullView for clarity)

I even tried this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Convert.ChangeType(myView, typeof(QuestionExtendedView))
```

No difference though. I can't seem to find other people having this issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sure, though I think that in this case it will distract from the issue itself. Give me 15mins to put it together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AuditFullView` class inherits from [`EntityObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx), which is marked with a [`DataContract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute. Because of this, JSON.NET requires that all properties must opt-in to serialization using [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attributes. Any properties without the attribute will be ignored by the serializer.

The properties on `AuditFullView` are marked with `DataMember`, so they're included when serializing; the properties on `QuestionExtendedView` aren't marked with `DataMember`, so they're ignored.

So the straightforward solution is to mark-up the properties of your `QuestionExtendedView` class with `DataMember` attributes.